# telnet - is there a maximum line limit?

Tags: http, telnet

I am working on several servers that use HTTP for transport of commands.

What I have encountered is that some of the commands I am trying to issue by hand are very long GETs, several lines, and that when I telnet from my Mac to my Solaris system, I cannot seem to cut and paste the line successfully.

I get a couple bounching sounds (which I assume is a control-g - bell) and then it never pastes everything.

From trying to break it up into smaller pieces, I am getting the impression that TELNET, or my bundled telnet client or server has a maximum line length that I had never bumped into.

I did some googling and superusering, but did not find anything definitive.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure that there is no actual hard limit as I have done a lot of funky things through telnet.

I can only imagine that as you are hearing a beep, you have reached the limit/buffer of the session and/or the client is simply hard coded to a limit of characters.

If it was a limit on the server, it would of responded with an error upon sending the data and reaching the character limit.

You can try an alternate client such as [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) which handles Telnet connections very well.

(this is based on my past experiences, but I am not 100% sure as without being in the same situation, I cannot test it, if I am wrong, please say and I will delete my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I experience this too, on OS X. For my purposes (also making manual HTTP requests!) I just put the request into a file and used `cat request.txt | nc localhost 8080` to send the data.